# When I install Axios an audit error occurs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

This is the error I get when running the command `npm i axios`:

```
up to date, audited 1469 packages in 6s

226 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Here, I use VS code and typed that command on its terminal.

I keep getting this error when trying to install `axios`, and I am not sure how to fix this.

Could this be a problem for my future coding?

Comment: What do you use, npm or yarn?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the new npm version including the audit command.

It isn't some new issue with the CLI, npm just introduced new functionality in npm to warn users about vulnerabilities in the packages they're installing - so there's no "new" vulnerability, it's just that now npm is now warning you about vulnerabilities that already existed: https://blog.npmjs.org/

If you have run `npm audit` and got vulnerabilities, then you can have different scenarios:

Security vulnerabilities found with suggested updates

- Run the npm audit fix subcommand to automatically install compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies.
- Run the recommended commands individually to install updates to vulnerable dependencies. (Some updates may be semver-breaking changes; for more information, see "SEMVER warnings".)

Security vulnerabilities found requiring manual review

- If security vulnerabilities are found, but no patches are available, the audit report will provide information about the vulnerability so you can investigate further.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit#reviewing-and-acting-on-the-security-audit-report).

Even after running `npm audit fix` if it is not fixed, then you can *Turn off* `npm audit`. Use the below command to turn off the `npm audit`.

When installing a single package:

```
npm install example-package-name --no-audit
```

To turn off npm audit when installing all packages:

```
npm set audit false
```

It will set the audit setting to false in your user and global `npmrc` config files.

*If you still want to fix them, you can refer to [this](https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d) article about how to.*